# Library feedback - for C++

Tags: c++11

I've written a new library, with an idea in it which I feel is fairly original. I'm looking for general feedback on it, and decided that I could submit to Boost- regardless of if it's rejected or accepted, I'd get some feedback. But I've checked the Boost site and it's seriously arcane, the whole mailing list thing is completely impenetrable.

Are there other library aggregation sites to submit to, or is it just Boost?

Comment: Why not host it on an open source site like Github? Many such sites have very strong collaboration and feedback features.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the library anyway? Perhaps the SO community would have some feedback as well?

Comment: @Tom: Pretty sure that you can't ask that here, else I would.

Comment: FWIW, news.ycombinator.com or reddit.com/r/programming might be good places too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reddit.com/r/programming may be a good place to get some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You could post to any of a myriad of open-source hosting sites -- see this other question for recommendations:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490/best-open-source-project-hosting-site